# How to convert Timestamp to Date Data Type in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert Timestamp data type columns to Date datatype using:

`bq query -q  --destination_table=NEW_DATE_TABLE --replace "SELECT DATE(CURR_DT) AS CURR_DT from TEST.DATE_TABLE"`

The new table shows the column as `STRING` rather than `date`. Is there a way to convert timestamp to `date` data type.

[Requested Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmAwu.png)

Comment: Just checked the earlier question, why can't TIMESTAMP_MILLIS/ MICROS be used? Was this function not added back when the question was asked?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql), you can do the following:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(EXTRACT(DATE FROM curr_dt)) AS curr_dt FROM test.date_table
```

If curr_dt is repeated field, then the solution will look the following:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM curr_dt) FROM t.curr_dt
  ) AS curr_dt)
FROM test.date_table t
```

Comment: Thanks.  Switching to standard SQL and running the Extract date worked fine.

Comment: Quick question - Does this work for nested tables (repeated)?

Comment: Updated answer to include how to deal with repeated fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am encountering an issue when used with SQL as replace cannot detect Repeat column.  The Standard SQL syntax does not allow to detect "Repeated group.column".  SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT EXTRACT (DATE FROM DTL.SKU_CRT_DT ) FROM t.DTL
  ) as SKU_CRT_DT )
FROM IntegrationTest_SalesAggregator.POS_JRNL_SLS_DASHBOARD_BAK_20150101 t

Error: Column SKU_CRT_DT in SELECT * REPLACE list does not exist at [4:8]

Comment: Meaning I cannot load a table that has the following structure:  SLS_DT TIMESTAMP 
DTL RECORD REPEATED 
DTL.SKU_CRT_DT TIMESTAMP

Comment: Yes, the REPLACE trick won't work here, you will need to list unchanged columns manually.

Comment: I need the same use case, but I have _PARTITIONTIME (My table is partitioned one), so how to copy to the destination table with field _PARTITIONTIME?

Answer (score 16):

Consider below!
Works in both Legacy and Standard SQL

```
SELECT CAST(DATE(CURR_DT) AS DATE) AS CURR_DT FROM TEST.DATE_TABLE
```

> Added to address comment

Try below - as I mentioned above  - it works for both Legacy and Standard

```
SELECT CAST(DATE(CURR_DT) AS DATE) AS CURR_DT
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS CURR_DT)
```

if you are interested in making your case working with Legacy SQL - provide more details about CURR_DT field

Comment: Thanks.  It worked for Standard SQL.  It gives me an error when legacy sql box is checked.  May be I am not using it correctly...........Query Failed
Error: Invalid function name: DATE_CAST; did you mean DATE_ADD?
Job ID: np-sales-thd:bquijob_66fa6a82_15705fb227

Comment: it means that your field is not really of timestamp data type. see example  - i just added for prove

Comment: Btw, just noticed in the error message  - `DATE_CAST` - this is not part of my example - so it most likely fails somewhere else  - show whole query you used if you want to fix it

Comment: When I run your SQL (wrote based on current_timestamp()) with Standard SQL it gives today's date.  When I run the same SQL with Legacy SQL (box checked), it gives me the following error: Error: Invalid function name: DATE_CAST; did you mean DATE_ADD?

Comment: i believe you  - but believe me also  - i just run it again and it works for me - no "funny" errors. most interestingly - where this `DATE_CAST` comes from? can you post your screenshot with query editor visible and options expanded? something definitely wrong

Comment: i saw your image  - it is exactly what i am running and it works for me. Will think and update here if any idea. Would be great if someone from BigQuery Team will catch this and explain for us

Comment: Uploaded the Screen shot in my original post.

Comment: I need the same use case, but I have _PARTITIONTIME (My table is partitioned one), so how to copy to the destination table with field _PARTITIONTIME?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CURR_DT AS INT64)) AS CURR_DT FROM TEST.DATE_TABLE
```