# SQL - convert yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ to simple date with no time

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I need to convert date/time with this format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ to simple date with no time.

Example : 2020-10-21T07:28:48.021Z
to : 2020-10-21

CAST(XX AS TIMESTAMP) works fine, but it doesn't  drop the time in my sql query as i would like.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select date('2020-10-21T07:28:48.021Z')
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cast(field as date) OR try_cast( field as date)
/*
Try cast will not return error  if it is not convertable it will return null*/

Comment: biq quey doesn't like  : TRY_CAST(field AS DATE) as new_field

Comment: "Invalid date: '2020-10-21T07:28:48.021Z'

Comment: So you're using Big Query? That would be very  helpful information to include in the original question, since every sql database product handles dates a little different.

Comment: Yes Biq query.   No error with this, but it is not what i want : CAST(Dat_cre AS TIMESTAMP) as DATE

Answer (score 0):

It's done differently in different databases, but in DB2, it's super simple:

```
select date(thatTimestamp)
  from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

HTH !

Answer (score -1):

you want cast( 2020-10-21T07:28:48.021Z as date)

or

select cast(dateField as date) as [DateFieldName]

Comment: cast as date is not working ! That's my problem....

Comment: What dbms are you using?  The code above is for sql server.  In your example you said cast timestamp wasn't working.

Comment: Biq Query.  Cast Timestamp IS working but i get [date + time], and i only want [date]

Comment: My apologies.  Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374004/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-data-type-in-google-bigquery) and see if it gives you the answer.

Comment: Tanhks, i checked but i still have this:

Comment: > no error with this, but it is not what i want : CAST(Dat_cre AS TIMESTAMP) as DATE

Comment: Did you try the extract function?  I see you added the BigQuery tag.  I'm going to drop off for now since it isn't my expertise but hopefully that tag will help you get a more direct answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway DataGuy !